# Adobe sitecatalyst Processing rule to capture query string and URL separately

Tags: adobe-analytics

How to create a processing rule that will record the URL, but excluding the query string, in a variable say evar

How to create a processing rule that will record the query string of the page URLin a variable say evar

Comment: well, which is it? do you want the url without query string (if so, see my answer), or just the query string (see @ChrisdeGroot answer). You seem to be asking for both?

Answer (score 0):

Try "Page Query String"

See docs http://microsite.omniture.com/t2/help/en_US/reference/processing_rule_dimensions.html

Comment: he actually wants the opposite; everything *except* the query string.

Comment: actually.. his statements seem to conflict! first sentences says excluding, 2nd sentence says that's what he wants!

Answer (score 0):

Processing Rules aren't very powerful. It would be nice if they were to let you do a regex replace or match on the various items in the dropdown, because that would cover a wide range of scenarios including yours. Perhaps in the future they will allow for this.. they have the underlying code for it (you can do this in the classification rule builder, for example). But alas, Processing Rules fall short.

The best you can do is

`Overwrite Value` > `[eVar]` > `Concatenated Value`

Then for delimiter use `/`

And then for values use `Page Domain` and `Page Path`

The one caveat about this is that it does not include protocol. This is actually probably ideal because most people don't want to have multiple entries because of things like protocol - probably the same reason you want to exclude query string!

Speaking of classification rule builder.. as an alternative, you could just use a processing rule to pop your eVar with the full URL (`page URL`), and then create a classification for the eVar, and then use the classification rule builder to pop the classification with the URL w/out the query string.  All you have to do is a regex condition to match `^[^?]+` and then use `$0` for the value.

You can do anything with the classification that you can with the base eVar, and you get the benefit of having both full and partial in your reports.